# Nodejs on Azure where is output of the console log

Tags: node.js, azure, console.log

I deployed a nodejs web app on azure as an
App Service

How do i see the console.log from my application?

Comment: I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842355/azure-nodejs-console-log) and this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b6deab8-a147-48ca-80d7-03b2ca377a98/how-do-i-see-consolelog-output-from-nodejs-on-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), there are some ways to see the logs.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 15):

You can tail the log with the Azure CLI...

```
$ az webapp log tail --name <name of webapp> --resource-group <name of resource group>
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/log?view=azure-cli-latest)

Answer (score 11):

I just followed [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to enable **Application Logging (Filesystem)**, **Application Logging (Blob)** and found `console.log` and `console.error` would output logs under `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\`, you could use [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to view your log files or you could also access `https://{your-app-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/Application/index.html` and check the **stdout** and **stderr** type as follows:

[image]

Moreover, as [Azure Web App (Website) Logging - Tips and Tools](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/#.Ws2pF4huaUm) mentioned about application logs for node.js as follows:

> Setting application logs in the Azure portal
>
> **For node.js websites the way to write application logs is by writing to the console using console.log('message') and console.error('message') which goes to Information/Error level log entries. Currently the only supported target for the log files for node.js is the file system.**
>
> Other web site types like php and python are not supported for the application logs feature.

For logging into blob, you may leverage [winston-azure-blob-transport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-azure-blob-transport) for collecting the application logs from your Node.js web app into Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 7):

You can open a Log Stream using the azure portal.

[image]